# On the Wix Velo platform, is code placed in the "Page" area publicly visible?

Tags: javascript, velo

According to [this article](https://support.wix.com/en/article/velo-security-best-practices), code that is put in the **Page** area specifically is publicly accessible. They even include this image to demonstrate:

[image: Code visibility]

I have not been able to see code that is entered here on the published version of the site. Here is an example where I published a blank page with a code in the `onReady` function:
https://steven0790.wixsite.com/my-site/blank

[image]

When I go to this page and inspect and search, I can't find the code. I would expect it to be in a `<script>` tag.
[image]

I have also tried looking through links in the code in case this is saved in a .js file or something like that.

Can anyone confirm whether or not this code really is accessible?

Comment: Why not put something in there that actually does something, like console.log or alert, and check? If it does, it's "publicly accessible". Where the code might end up depends on how the site is packaged up..

Comment: Using console.log to output this value does work. If someone can figure out the packaging and find the code, that would be definitive. If it's publicly accessible, it shouldn't be that hard to find if you know what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the Console instead of the Elements tab in the browser developer tools. It will let you know which JS file contains your code.

Look for a message that looks something like this:

> Running the code for the HOME page. To debug this code in your browser's dev tools, open cnric.js.

You can then open that file in your browser developer tools and see the code.

Comment: It says "open mmber.js". I searched for this in the Elements tab to find the path to it. And sure enough, the code is buried in there. Thanks!